# [[likely]] [[unlikely]] и тернарный оператор

Tags: c++, c++17

Есть некая функция, которая определенным образом фильтрует контейнер. И в ней есть ветвление с защитой от дурака. В основном, она работает с контейнерами, так как предпочтительно ее будут вызывать именно для фильтрации контейнера, но есть небольшая вероятность, что ее случайно вызовут тогда, когда вместо контейнера будет обычный числовой тип. В общем, я бы хотел воспользоваться новой возможностью с++ 17 и подсказать компилятору, что это редкий случай. Но, кажется, теги [[likely]], [[unlikely]] не работают  с тернарным оператором, либо я что-то делаю не так. Вопрос: можно ли тут влепить эти теги, при условии, что valueOpt это редкая ветка?

```
template < typename T,
typename Filter,
typename Initial>
constexpr T greedy_algorithm(Filter const& filter, Initial initial) {
    std::optional<container_variant> containerOpt = any_to_variant_cast<ANY_VARIANTS>(_container);
    std::optional<T> valueOpt = get_optional_value<T>(_container); // редкий случай
    return (containerOpt)
        ? __greedy_algorithm<T>(*containerOpt, filter, initial)
        :  (valueOpt) // редкий случай
            ? filter(initial, *valueOpt)
            : initial;
    }
```

Comment: Эти теги на само условие, а не на бранч, если я правильно понимаю. Ваше условие `likely` здесь.

Comment: Условия в круглых скобках, после return, но не в случае если тег внутри скобок, ни в случае если тег слева от скобки не компилируется. Попробовал убрать круглые скобки, тоже не помогло. Это не большая проблема, больше из любопытства попробовал, первый блин комом :)

Answer (score 4):

[Предложение](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0479r5.html) по ссылке в википедии говорит:

> The attribute-tokens likely and unlikely may be applied to labels or statements

Т.е. можно добавить атрибут к метке или инструкции. А на ветку в тернарном операторе - нельзя. Нужно переписывать используя if.

Хочу еще пояснить [пример](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely), где на первый взгляд кажется, что используется атрибут на тернарном операторе:

```
    for (auto n{0LL}; n < precision; n += 2LL) {
        [[likely]] y += pow(x, n) / (n & 2LL ? -fact(n) : fact(n));
    }
```

На самом деле атрибут здесь указан для *всей инструкции* в цикле.  В цикле есть условное выполнение и два пути. Один путь выполнения - это выход из цикла, второй путь - с заходом в цикл. И задумка этого примера такая, чтоб подсказать компилятору, что путь выполнения c заходом в тело цикла чаще будет выполнятся чем путь без захода.

Comment: Ну вот в примерах тэг используется с тернарным оператором, в функции cos: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely

Comment: Да, тут пример может сбить с толку. Добавил объяснение в ответ.

Comment: Да, действительно. Не обратил внимание на скобку. Благодарю!